# android, how to force the notification to show on lock screen?

Tags: push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

in android lock screen settings, it has

1. Show all notification content
2. Show sensitive content only when unlocked
3. Don't show notification at all.

Trying to force to show the FCM push notification when it is in screen lock state.
tried put this the channel

```
"notificationChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);"
```

when the setting 'Don't show notification at all.' there is no notification shown until it goes out of the lock screen.
And this is same behavior with no set in the channel.

How is the Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC supposed to behavior?